# How do you redefine a constant variable in a derived class? [JAVA]

Tags: java, oop, constants, derived-class

Say I have a class

```
class A {
   public static final int x = 1;
}
```

and I have a derived class

```
class B extends A {
   x = 2; // want to redefine x as 2 here
}
```

How would I go about for redefining the constant as 2 in the derived class B? I recall there being a constructor "trick" when working with C++, but I am lost on what to do in Java. I even tried removing the "final" from the variable declaration in Class A, but Class B doesn't even know X is defined. It says I need to add the "public static final int" in front of the x in Class B, but I thought it was already defined in A.

Comment: You can't you only can "shadow" it . `public static final int x=2` . Static belong to class you can't have polymorphic in variables or in static things

Comment: @nachokk, so I am taking it that when class B is instantiated, when member variable x is called, its value is 2?

Comment: Statics are *not members* of instances. Get that committed.

Comment: A static variable is a thing associated with the class.  "When class B is instantiated," there is no member x.  (And you can't override fields, even non-static ones.)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Static belong to class not to instances.

But to make a trick you can create another constant with the same name.
You access to that constant with

### A.x or B.x

```
class B extends A {
  public static final x = 2;
}
```

In this example `A.x=1` and `B.x=2`

Or if you want to redefine as you asked you can do this but it's pointless

```
class B extends A{
  static{
    x=2;// assuming 'x' not final
  }
}
```

In this example `A.x=2` and `B.x=2`

Comment: Does the static{ ... } block of code in class B mean that the Class B will have a static variable of x, of which the value is 2? And A would remain unaffected with its static variable of x having a value of 1?

Comment: @Jay In class B you are redifining "x" defined in class A, so you lose that value :D , it's pointless doing that.

Comment: So class A will have its static variable = 1 and class B will have its static variable = 2? If so, this is a perfect solution.

Comment: According to the selected answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355033/static-variable-in-subclass-java), it is not possible to override static variables. So I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Jay you are not overriding, you are creating a new one, i think this is call shadowing!

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT possible. *public static final int* is a *compile time constant* it cannot be re-initialized.

Comment: But even when I remove the "final", it still thinks x is undefined in Class B.

Comment: Static means class scope, not instance, thus you have to fully qualify it, `A.x`.

Comment: @m0skit0 no you don't.

Comment: @m0skit0 - The non-private fields of the parent are directly accessible using the instance itself (even if they are static)

Comment: @DavidWallace I know. Note I didn't mean *always*. IMHO it's always better to fully qualify it, it's more clear.

Comment: @Jay the reason for the "undefined in class B" after you remove the final is that you've got a line of code that isn't a declaration, isn't in a static block, and isn't in a method.  When exactly is such a line supposed to run?

Comment: Note that you could put `x` in an *instance level block* as well

Comment: @DavidWallace After removing `final` it is `public static int x = 1`. I don't see how this is not a declaration.

Comment: @TheLostMind is correct - it could also be in an instance initialiser.  That's one more case.  But where it is, it's just a "naked" line of code.  That's the error.  Nothing to do with visibility or accessibility.

Comment: @m0skit0 I'm talking about the `x=2;` in class B.

Comment: @DavidWallace, so redefining x in the constructor for B would fix the issue, correct?

Comment: @Jay - and removing `final`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what @RenéWinkler's answer does.  And you don't need the `A.` in front of the `x`, although some people prefer to leave it in.

Answer (score 0):

I f you remove the final keyword, you can assign x in the constructor of B as follows:

```
  class B extends A {

   public B(){
       A.x = 2;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of having final is that, no one should be able to change it.

Here is a sample code if you just want to use static:

```
class Test2{
  public static int a=0; // if you use final here the code will not compile
}

class B extends Test2{
  //a = 1000; - this requires a datatype
  public void setA(){
    a=1000;
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}


class C{
  public static void main(String args[]){
      B objB = new B();
      objB.setA();
  }
}
```